# Interpolation using Gaussian processes

Tags: machine-learning, inference, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, interpolation

This is about Gaussian process interpolations, where the given data are f(0) = 1, f(0.4) = 3 and f(1) = 2. Assume that the covariance function used is the exponential covariance, where the expectation is 0 throughout.

[image: 1]

How would you interpolate the values such as f(0.1), f(0.2), and f(0.7)?

Follow-up question: if the expectation of the Gaussian process is E[X(t)] = 0.1 (instead of E[X(t)] = 0), how would you interpolate the values such as f(0.1), f(0.2), and f(0.7)?

Note: this is not a homework question.

Edit: I know that the expression below is used to interpolate missing values, but I am still unsure about a couple of things. First, is this interpolation not deterministic, meaning whatever parameters we obtain for the multivariate Gaussian distribution, that we are still sampling from that distribution? Also, what does f, K(X*, X), and K(X, X) mean?

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the multivariate normal distribution? GP interpolators simply use the conditional Normal equations

Comment: You might find it helpful to consult a textbook about Gaussian processes such as http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/

Comment: I have looked through that book. I feel that I understand the idea at a high level. Do I just sample a multi gaussian distribution? I am not 100% sure where to start.

Comment: I believe you're looking for eq 2.19.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: The text explains what the notation means. What part of the text's explanations do you find confusing?

Comment: Never mind, I understand the notation better. Are we still sampling from the multivariate Gaussian distribution, as the above expression shows?

Comment: I think it might be more helpful for you to post an answer for more specificity.

Comment: Yes, $a \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is commonly used to denote sampling from a normal distribution.

Comment: Is K(X∗, X)K(X, X) ^(−1 )*f a vector or a matrix?

Comment: @Tony it is a vector, because f is a vector